# Verificação de campos ComboBox, TextBox MaskedTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Como criar um método para verificar se todos os campos "ComboBox, TextBox MaskedTextBox" estão preenchidos? O meu não funciona

```
public bool CampoVazio()
{
    bool ok = false;
    foreach(Control ctrl in this.Controls)
      {
          if(ctrl is TextBox)
            {
              if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrl.Text))
                 {
                    ok= true;
                    break;
                 }
            }
        }
    return ok;
}
```

Comment: "Entre outros" pode comportar um monte de coisa, cara. Por favor, especifique quais são os outros. Aliás, seu código faz bem pouco sentido.

Comment: Por isso estou pedindo ajuda.

Comment: "Entre outros" pode comportar um monte de coisa, cara. **Por favor, especifique quais são os outros**

Comment: Entre outros seria entradas de texto. É só seguir os exemplos citados.

Comment: ComboBox não é entrada de texto...

Comment: Vou explicar melhor. Tenho um layout, e quero verificar se todos os campos estão devidamente preenchido.

Comment: Perdão, você está correto. De qualquer forma preciso pegar o valor do item selecionado nele.

Comment: Ok, jovem. Isso é certo. O que eu quero saber é, quais são os controles que você pretende validar neste método? Apenas `TextBoxes` e `ComboBoxes`?

Comment: Tenho 3 elementos que preciso verificar, ComboBox, TextBox e MaskedTextBox.

Comment: Agora sim!!!!!!!

Comment: Desculpe, iniciante aqui, não quero colocar uma condicional para cada elemento o codigo ficaria grande demais, se houver outra forma de fazer agradeço.

Comment: Infelizmente não fui capaz de resolver, encontrei uma solução que é verificar o objeto passado para o banco de dados, então vou fazer assim e continuar estudando as opções apresentadas até entender 100% oque acontece.

Answer (score 4):

Basicamente você precisa validar todos os campos que sejam `TextBoxBase` (isso inclui todos os tipos de `TextBox`) ou `ComboBox` ou se eles têm "filhos", neste caso, é preciso chamar a função novamente passando o controle como parâmetro.

O método retorna `true` se todos os campos foram devidamente preenchidos.

```
private bool VerificaCamposPreenchidos(Control parent = null)
{
    if (parent == null)
        parent = this;

    foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBoxBase)
        {
            var txt = (TextBoxBase)control;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text))
                return false;
        }

        if (control is ComboBox)
        {
            var cmb = (ComboBox)control;
            if (cmb.SelectedValue == null)
                return false;
        }

        if (control.HasChildren)
        {
            if (!VerificaCamposPreenchidos(control))
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Posso saber o que está errado?

Comment: Pra mim aqui apresentou erro ao carregar parent = this;

Comment: Eu já editei @RonivaldoRoner

Comment: Estou estudando o seu método aqui, porem da forma que está, só retorna true, mesmo todos estando preenchidos ou não.

Comment: Não, @RonivaldoRoner. Ele só retorna `true` quando todos estiverem preenchidos.

Comment: Pois bem, eu fiz testes e ta retornando false mesmo todos os campos preenchidos, add MessagBox para analisar cada passo e percebi que ele esta deixando 2 campos sem verificar, um deles é um MaskedTextBox, e outro TextBox com Multilinha = true. engraçado é que ele esta vendo outros MaskedTexBox e TextBox, eu vou continuar analisando, acredito estar próximo da solução.

Comment: Ele está deixando sem verificar como? Passando reto por eles?

Comment: Exatamente. Add um MessageBox em cada -if- para imprimir control.Text e ver o conteúdo de cada elemento. e 2 elementos simplesmente são ignorados.

Comment: Você não consegue debuggar o código?

Comment: Estou tentando aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize uma função recursiva, de modo que percorra o controle e seus filhos:

```
    public static bool CamposVazios(Control _ctrl)
    {
        foreach (Control c in _ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)c).Text))
                    return true;
            }
            else if (c is ComboBox)
            {
                if (((ComboBox)c).SelectedValue == null)
                    return true;
            }
            else if (c.HasChildren)
            {
                if (CamposVazios(c))
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Para chamar ela, dentro de um Form:

```
if (CamposVazios(this))
{
  //Há algum campo vazio.
}
```

Sugestão:

No meu caso, eu coloco uma `Exception` quando o campo está em branco, pois aí consigo informar ao usuário qual campo que está inválido, destacar o campo ou qualquer coisa do tipo. Ex:

```
    public static void CamposVazios(Control _ctrl)
    {
        foreach (Control c in _ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (c.HasChildren)
            {
                CamposVazios(c);
            }
            else if (c is TextBox)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)c).Text))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Campo "+ c.Name + " está vazio");
                }
            }
            else if (c is ComboBox)
            {
                if (((ComboBox)c).SelectedValue == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Campo "+ c.Name + " está vazio");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

e na hora de chamar a função:

```
try 
{
   CamposVazios(this);
   //Processar / Gravar / etc...
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta está errada. Se tiver um painel com um textbox dentro dele e um textbox fora dele o só o último retorno vai valer. Ou seja, o retorno vai ser `false` e deveria ser `true`.

Comment: Acertei, obrigado

Comment: Outra coisa errada é a utilização de excepções para indicar que há campos vazios,

Comment: Eu vou retirar o voto negativo. Agora funciona, mas eu acho má ideia usar exceções.

Comment: foi só uma sugestão, que eu utilizo. Há algum motivo específico para não utilizar as exceções? Uma observação que utilizo esse código como uma função em uma outra classe e todos os Forms da aplicação podem acessá-la.

Comment: Excepções devem ser usadas para situações excepcionais e não para controle de fluxo. Em vez de lançar uma excepção o método `CamposVazios()` deveria retornar uma lista com os nomes dos campos vazios. Assim, após chamá-lo, é possível verificar se há ou não campos vazios e se sim construir uma mensagem com o nome deles.

Comment: @ramaral ok, obrigado pela informação.

Comment: Fiz alguns testes e só retorna true mesto tendo campos vazios ou não. Vou estudar em cima do seu método para entender melhor.

Comment: Esse erro foi acertado ontem mesmo na edição